# Python: How to parent an object to a bone without transformation?

Tags: python, bones, transforms, parent

I'm trying to parent an object to a specific bone. I need to assign 100% bone weights to all vertices, to be able to read this as a skeletal mesh in Unreal Engine. I'm using this code:

```
ob= bpy.data.objects['Cube']
arma = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

ob.parent = arma
ob.parent_bone = "Bone"
ob.parent_type = 'BONE'
```

... It works, but the object changes its transform. How can I parent it without changing transform of the object? Here is my simple test blend file:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46227

Please click the 'Run Script' button to see the issue.

I would be grateful for some hints. I've tried the matrix multiplication (matrix_world.inverted()), but it doesn't work for bones.

For example, Ctrl + P in editor does it properly - it parents an object to a bone without moving it.
Thanks!

**Update:** I've also thought about assigning all the object's vertices to a bone with 100% weight - but I can't find any info on this one, I'm afraid that it's not possible? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `bpy.ops.object.parent_set()` and using the `keep_transform` parameter. I also allowed to choose which bone of your armature you want it to be the parent by setting `parent_bone = 'BoneNameYouWantToBeParent'`as shown below:

```
import bpy

ob= bpy.data.objects['Cube']
arma = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
arma.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arma 

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

parent_bone = 'Bone' # choose the bone name which you want to be the parent

arma.data.edit_bones.active = arma.data.edit_bones[parent_bone]

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all objects
ob.select = True
arma.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arma    #the active object will be the parent of all selected object

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='BONE', keep_transform=True)
```

As shown below I modified your armature to have multiple bones so you can select which bone you want it to be the parent to your Cube. In the below screenshot I used `Bone` to be the parent:

[image]

In the screenshot below I chose `Bone.001` to be the parent:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Thank you! + To make this a skeletal mesh (recognizable in e.g. Unreal Engine), it's also necessary to assign vertex groups. In my case I did something like this:
https://pastebin.com/XMfNYyC3

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this in the future, this code works, but you will need to update Taks code for Blender 3.0+:

`arma.select_set(True)` and `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = arma`

So updated script looks like:

```
import bpy

ob= bpy.data.objects['Cube']
arma = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

arma.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = arma

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')


parent_bone = 'Bone'  # choose the bone name which you want to be the parent

arma.data.edit_bones.active = arma.data.edit_bones[parent_bone]

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')  # deselect all objects
ob.select_set(True)
arma.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = arma
# the active object will be the parent of all selected object

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='BONE', keep_transform=True)
```